# Initializing a string, why is `@` required?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm really new to Objective-C but I'm experienced in C/C++, so a few things look strange to me. I'm reading a tutorial that shows the basics of Objective-C and the author warns me about forgetting to include the `@` before my string. So, for instance

`"Hello"` vs `@"Hello"`

However, the author doesn't explain why the `@` is required or what its syntactical meaning is. So that's what I'm asking now, what does the `@` do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a `NSString` literal. Without the `@`, you'd be creating a `char *`, which is not an object like `NSString`.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is a super set of C, so you should know `"hello"` is a C string (`const char *`).

`@"hello"` is something different, it is `NSString *`. `NSString` is ObjC object, that you can send message to it and use like object. You can't do it with C string.

for example, to get length from these two string:

```
NSString *objcStr = @"hello";

int len = [objcStr length];

const char * cStr = "hello";

len = strlen(cStr);
```

Comment: You can even do things like: `NSUInteger len = [@"Hello" length];`.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `@` designates features that are unique to Objective C and are not in raw C. In this case, if you want an Objective C `NSString` object as a literal, you use `@` otherwise you end up with a different type of character string that is not an Objective C object but rather a raw C entity.